# Ionic 2 'col-n' attribute not working

Tags: ionic2

I am unable to create columns that span 'n' number of columns with the `col-n` attribute. Not even the example provided in the guides. This currently displays for me 2 rows with 3 columns, all the same size:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      1 of 3
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-8>
      2 of 3 (wider)
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      3 of 3
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      1 of 3
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>
      2 of 3 (wider)
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      3 of 3
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Ionic version: 2.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can you like this:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col width-20></ion-col>
    <ion-col width-80></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

the first column will take up 20% of the width, and the second column will take up the remaining 80% of the width. You can use any combination of the following that adds up to 100:

width-10
width-20
width-25
width-33
width-50
width-67
width-75
width-80
width-90

Comment: Where is this documented?  I keep getting redirected to the v3 docs

Answer (score 2):

The attributes `col-*`are available for the version 3 of Ionic, as documentation points out. The right grid attributes for version 2are the propoded by the accepted answer by @coenni.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that points that out?